# Construction of key recovery attack in O(2^(n/2))

Tags: block-cipher, key-recovery, spn

I have to construct a key recovery attack on symmetric key encryption using a publicly known permutation $\Pi$  in $O(2^\frac{n}{2})$  time using $2^\frac{n}{2}$ queries to an encryption oracle.

The encryption is done as
$ \Pi ( m \oplus K) \oplus K $, where $K$ is the key. Both $m$ and $K$ belong to ${0, 1}^{n}$

I do not know how I can use the queries to do the key recovery attack in that time.
I can check my guesses against the output of the queries for $2^\frac{n}{2}$ of them. But how will I recover the key successfully ?

Really need some help here.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @poncho One of the practice problems. Not exactly homework.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you said that this was a "practice problem"; hence you're supposed to learn from it, so I won't give you the answer.

I will give you a hint: you have $E_k(M) = \Pi(M \oplus K) \oplus K$; suppose you defined $F_k(M) = E_k(M) \oplus E_k(M \oplus 1)$, and further defined $G$ such that $F_k(M) = G( M \oplus K )$ (and yes, such a $G$ exists independent of $K$).  How could you use that to do key recovery?